# Error while sorting a datagrid table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I tried to sort a datagrid column when clicked and I ended up with this error message:

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find column ibsn.

The code works fine for the other columns. Not really sure where i went wrong.

```
Sub Sort_Grid(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridSortCommandEventArgs)
    if Session("MyCurrentSort") = e.SortExpression then
        Session("MyCurrentSort") = e.SortExpression & " desc"
    else
        Session("MyCurrentSort") = e.SortExpression
    end if
    BindGrid()
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think the error happen in the code you wrote down. I would assume that the column ibsn does not exists. It might be an other name.

Comment: in the data grid, I had SortExpression="isbn" when it should have been SortExpression="ISBN"